# SQL - Calculating minimum difference between current row value and ONLY the rows above

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large coordinate based dataset of cities, where each city has a score and a set of coordinates which indicates the exact point where the score was taken.

There are no duplicate city names in the dataset as I've already cleansed the data by taking only the highest score from each instance of a city string. However there are locations where multiple boroughs of 1 city are included e.g. Brooklyn, Queens etc., and in some worldwide locations like Dubai there are hundreds of these boroughs.

| City | Score | latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 100 | x | y |
| Singapore | 98.5 | x | y |
| Toronto | 96.7 | x | y |
| ... |  |  |  |

I have code which can calculate the difference between two lat/long points in metres that works nicely in SQL. What I need to do is run it through my dataset and find the minimum distance for only the rows above the one being calculated, so if in my table above for Toronto it would find the minimum distance between Toronto & NY, & Toronto & Singapore and then obviously return the Toronto/NY result.

Then I can filter by this mindistance (like WHERE mindistance > 4000)  to prevent most of these multiple borough cities from appearing and therefore making my dataset useful.

As I'm only interested in the highest score in each city I only need to calculate this distance from the rows above in each case as the rows below will always have a lower score, hope that makes sense.

I've not been able to try anything along the lines presented above, I've tried searching for how to run something like a for loop in SQL but unsure how to make it only analyse the rows above in the table.

Comment: Hi - what is your definition of "above"? As records in a database table have no intrinsic order, how do you determine, for any given record, which other records you want to compare it to? Also, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, etc.) - as the answer is likely need to be specific to the capabilities of your specific DBMS

Comment: Hello Nick, sorry I'm a bit new to stack-overflow. We are using MS SQL Server. The cities are ranked by the score they are given, I can add an ID field easily so in this case New York ID = 1, Singapore = 2, Toronto = 3. I would only want to compare each record to those with an ID less than it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that "above" means smaller id than current,
and assuming you want a new column of the nearest city id-

```
SELECT      C.Id,
            C.City,
            ...,
            (
                SELECT      TOP(1)  C2.Id
                FROM        Cities  AS  C2
                WHERE       C2.Id   <   C.Id
                ORDER BY    ABS(C2.Latitude - C.Latitude)   --> put distance formula here
            )   AS          NearestCityId
            
FROM        Cities  AS  C
ORDER BY    C.Id
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect with very minor adjustments, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sample schema and data:

```
create table cities 
(id int,
city varchar(100),
point geography);

insert into cities values (1, 'New York', 'POINT (-73.4 40.35)');
insert into cities values (2, 'Toronto', 'POINT (-79.34 43.65)');
insert into cities values (3, 'Singapore', 'POINT (103.85 1.29)');
insert into cities values (4, 'Tokyo', 'POINT (139.84 35.65)');
insert into cities values (5, 'Chicago', 'POINT (-87.62 41.88)');
insert into cities values (6, 'Milwaukee', 'POINT (-87.91 43.04)');
```

Query:

```
with cte as (
select
  c1.city as city1,
  c2.city as city2,
  c1.point.STDistance(c2.point) as dist
from cities c1
inner join cities c2
on c1.id > c2.id
),
cte2 as (
select
  row_number() over (partition by city1 order by dist asc) as row_number, 
  city1,
  city2,
  dist
from cte
)
select
  city1 as city,
  city2 as nearest_previous_city,
  dist
from cte2
where row_number = 1
```

The steps are as follows:

- `cte` calculates the distance between the given city and all previous cities (`c1.id > c2.id`)
- `cte2` orders neighboring cities for each city by the distance, and gives them a rank (`partition by city1 order by dist asc`))
- for each city with predecessors, `cte3` selects the city in the nearest distance (`row_number = 1`)